# How to save in JSON file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save data to the JSON file using save but haven't achieved it. Any help please!!!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to write to a local JSON file using `$resource`?

Comment: You need a back-end of some sort to write to files.

Comment: @jimakos17 you need to treat your POST request server-side, what do you use server-side?

Comment: Where is the file?  What code have you written to try to save data to the file and where is it running?

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question : as @James Kleeh has mentioned, you need some back-end, because when you evoke save method on your `$resource object`, all it does is send `$http POST request` to the specified url, with corresponding json data and so your back-end have to handle this request and return a response. If you use a json file stored localy or remote without back-end it simply doesn't know what to do with this request and some json data.
For the second : you can look towards the CouchDB that uses JSON.